# Формы и нострока формы

Tags: css

Как сделать красивые кнопки и текст формы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте!
За *"красивые кнопки и оформление текста"* (впрочем, за оформление любого элемента вашего сайта) отвечает **файл CSS**.

Для того, чтобы начать использовать **CSS** (Каскадные таблицы стилей), вам нужно создать файл **style.css** (к примеру). Затем в **html** страничке **подключить** этот файл стилей:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ваш_сайт/style.css" />
```

Потом отредактировать **style.css** под свои нужды.

Для того, чтобы разобраться во всём этом, посетите [этот сайт.](http://ru.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson1.php)

Answer (score 0):

это называется CSS, вот [ссылочка](http://efimov.ws/) , там есть готовые решения

Answer (score 0):

А также есть интересный фреймворк [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). Вот только слишком увлекаться не советую, чтобы сайт не потерял уникальность дизайна.